# HTML Heading Tag

Tags: html, web, html5-canvas, web-development-server, mdns

Can we use multiple `<h1>` tag in a web page? If not then why not?

I have though is there any warning or any issue to use multiple `<h1>` tag in a web page. Is it a good practice or good to use multiple heading tag in a web page. Is structurally correct?

I'm learning html where I learn there are there six hading tag from h1 to h6 , So I though it is possible to or a good practice to use multiple heading tag of same semantics .

I'm trying to add multiple heading tag of same semantics in a web page . It works properly . I want to know is it a good practice to use multiple heading tag of same semantics in a web page ?

Answer (score -2):

It is perfectly fine to add multiple  tags. However, you might want to ensure that each  tag is in a separate section/topic within the document (for accessibility, maintainability and SEO).